VS Code terminal doesn't print correctly all characters in my java code
I have this simple code that should print these characters
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.print("名 é à è €");
    }
}

But whenever I run and debug in VS Code my project, the output in the terminal is this:

I tried to enter chcp 65001 to fix it but it does not correct the isssue and here's the output after:

I tried to do these things outside of VS Code by doing javac and java and this is what I got:
Without chcp 65001:

With chcp 65001:

Here's my javac version:
javac 22.0.1

does your last screenshot not show it working?

Yes it works, but not in the vscode terminal as i said

what if you just run echo '名 é à è €' in a shell in VS Code's integrated terminal?

It works fine, so it's a problem of the java compiler ?

[edit] to add the output of javac --version

this issue could be the cause of the coding error. By default, vscode uses UTF-8 encoding, and the computer uses GBK. I tried changing the computer settings to work fine:

Go to the computer settings, select Time&Language, select Language&region, Administrative language settings, Change system locale, and tick the Beta version.
Restart vscode to try to run the code.



It works! But I have one question: since this feature is in beta, could it break some application text?

Hi, the beta version may have some impact on the system. You can also try adding it in settings.json file
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
"JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS": "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
}. Then restart vscode after saving and try again.
